# Creating a list with enumerate

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

By using

```
\begin{enumerate}

...  

\end{enumerate}
```

I intent to create a list just like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{1)}

\noindent \textbf{a)}

\medskip

\noindent \textbf{b)} 

\bigskip

\noindent \textbf{2)}

\end{document}
```

Some hint for this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Somethin like this? I am not sure about the spacing you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent Abc

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=10pt, itemsep=5pt, align=left, label=\textbf{\arabic*)}]
    \item \
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=10pt, itemsep=5pt, topsep=0pt, align=left, label=\textbf{\alph*)}]
        \item 
        \item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The slash after the first `\item` is just to make the next `enumerate` align correctly, although there is currently no text after this item. It can be safely replaced with other text.

For more details, I recommend you to take a look at the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much. Another question: if I want no space between \textbf{1)} and \textbf{a)}?

Comment: I updated my suggestion. Since you want everything left aligned with the other text, it is easier to use fixed widths. You can use `topsep=0pt` for the nested `enumerate` to remove the space before.

Comment: It's perfect. Many thanks.